# Get index as datetime object from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I got a csv file that looks like this

```
valid,temp,pressure
2019-11-25 12:00,22,4
2019-11-22 12:00,24,4
2019-11-20 12:00,24,5
2019-11-17 12:00,26,5
```

I read the csv as a pandas dataframe and set the valid column as the index. I also convert it to a pd.datetime

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
pd.to_datetime(df['valid'])  # convert 'valid' column to pd.datetime objects
df = df.set_index('valid')  # set the 'valid' column as index
```

Now I want to get the index as a datetime object of a certain row. How do I do that?

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
row = df.iloc[2]
print(row.index.month)  # using .month just see if the returned object is a pd.datetime

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'month'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign back, because `to_datetime` is not `inplace` function and then test `Series.name`, because if select one row it return `Series` with name by index of row in `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df['valid'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid'])
df = df.set_index('valid')
row = df.iloc[2]

print (row)
temp        24
pressure     5
Name: 2019-11-20 12:00:00, dtype: int64

print (row.name)
2019-11-20 12:00:00

print (row.name.month)
11
```

Also for convert column to datetimes is possible use `parse_dates` and `index_col` parameter in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['valid'], index_col=['valid'])
row = df.iloc[2]
print (row.name.month)
11
```

Comment: without assigning it back am I essentially not doing it in the first place?

Comment: @Vader - You do it, but no effect, because not inplace function.

Comment: I still get the same error after your suggested change.

Comment: df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.valid)).drop("valid", axis=1)